# Cannot resolve symbol '@string/default_notification_channel_id'

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up a Firebase Cloud Messaging Client app on Android. I am using https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging as a guideline or template for my implementation. When I try to write the code at https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml, I see the `Cannot resolve symbol '@string/default_notification_channel_id'` error in the following line:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>
```

[image]

Do you have any ideas about a fix for this error? Thank you.

Comment: Is this in your values/strings.xml?

Comment: @alfasin I copied/pasted from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#manifest, and it is `@string/default_notification_channel_id`, exactly the way I wrote it.

Comment: @Phix Where is the `values/strings.xml` file typically placed within an Android project?

Comment: You'll need to create this string in your src/main/res/values/strings.xml directory (which it is in that project). I recommend cloning that project vs. cherry picking files for this reason.

Comment: @Phix I am cherry picking because I have an app already working with Urban Airship for push notifications, but I am trying to migrate to FCM. But if things do not work for me, maybe I will have to clone that project, test, and then implement it in my system when I understand everything sufficiently.

Comment: You'll need to make sure you'll need to grab whatever resources are being referenced here `@string`, `@color` etc.

Comment: @Phix It fixed the problem what you said. Please put your solution as an answer so that I can choose it to report this question as solved.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Go to your string resource in res > value > string.xml or simply click alt+enter and paste this code under the resource block:

```
 <string name="default_notification_channel_id" translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>
```

If you are using the shortcut go tho create string resource and paste "News" in value.

Answer (score 1):

in this path: **android\app\src\main\res**, Create a new folder if it doesn't exist **values**. then create a new file with the name: **string.xml**

Then copy these lines into the file.-->

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <string name="default_notification_channel_id" 
           translatable="false">fcm_default_channel</string>
 </resources>
```